# cakephp calculations in virtual field with sorting

Tags: php, cakephp

I want to create a dummy field say status. That stores a number from 1-5 based on some calculations (shown below). How do i do it? I want this field to be sortable. Where/how in the model do i write this code so that this field is sortable?

```
if(empty($booksUser['BooksUser']['returned_on_date'])){
    if(date('Y-m-d') > $booksUser['BooksUser']['return_by_date']){
        $booksUser['BooksUser']['status'] = 1;
    } else {
        $booksUser['BooksUser']['status'] =  2;
    }
} else {
    if($booksUser['BooksUser']['returned_on_date'] > $booksUser['BooksUser']['return_by_date']) {
        $booksUser['BooksUser']['status'] = 3;
    } else {
        $booksUser['BooksUser']['status'] = 4;
    }
}
```

Comment: Literally what? I have no idea what you're asking

Comment: does this make sense

Comment: You are aware that sorting normally happens at DB level?

Comment: So why not using a virtual field? When that can actually do what you ask?

Comment: mark plz tell me how. From my understanding virtual fields are for sql level fields like doing concat. can i do the above

Comment: as mark says, a virtual field is what you're looking for

Comment: @mcgowan.b plz tell me how. some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @mark after some research i was able to create a virtual field . here is my query from which i created `status` as virtual field

```
select 
    IF(isnull(returned_on_date), 
            IF(CURDATE() < return_by_date, 1, 2), 
            IF(returned_on_date > return_by_date, 3, 4)
    ) as status 
from books_users
```

Answer (score 0):

Just took a quick look at this.

I would suggest doing what you have and then sorting it after the fact with CakePHP Set::sort.

Refer to here...
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/set.html#Set::sort